# In a metabelian group $M$, is it true that $[[u,g],f] = [[u,f],g]$ for $u\in M'$, $g,h\in M$?

Tags: group-theory

It is stated in $\S$1 of Romankov's:

[Generators of Automorphisms of Free Metabelian pro-$p$ groups](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vitaly_Romankov2/publication/266435652_Generating_elements_of_automorphism_groups_of_free_metabelian_pro-p-_groups/links/544f89ef0cf2bca5ce92904f.pdf?inViewer=0&pdfJsDownload=0&origin=publication_detail)

that if $M$ is a metabelian group, $u\in M'$, then for any $g,f$, we have $[[u,g],f] = [[u,f],g]$.

Is this true? I can't seem to verify this...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is well-known, and a proof can be found in many references, e.g., in Lemma 3.1. at page $7$ [here](http://mathstat.slu.edu/~jackson/research/basic.pdf). It states that for a metabelian group $G$ we have
$$
[c,b,a]=[c,a,b]
$$ 
for all $a\in G'=[G,G]$, with the notation $[a,b,c]=[[a,b],c]$.
For the proof one first shows the
*Hall-Witt identity*
$$
[c, b, a] = [b, a, c]^{−1} [c, a, b] 
$$
which holds for all groups, and then derives the result as a corollary.